# jQuery draggable and droppable together with data() returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been playing around with this piece of code and everything seemed to work just fine. When I drag one of the yellow boxes over the red container, the variable `price` is incremented with the `data-price` value and then subtracted when the yellow box goes out of the red container.

The issue comes up when I drag them back over the red container one more time and results in NaN. `$(".draggable[data-item='" + value + "']").data('price');` seems to be undefined.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  var price = 0, math = '', items = [];
  function calcPrice(math) {
      console.log(items);
      $.each( items, function( key, value ) {
        if(math == 'add')
          price += $(".draggable[data-item='" + value + "']").data('price');
        if(math == 'remove')
          price -= $(".draggable[data-item='" + value + "']").data('price');
      });
    $("#droppable").text(price);
  }
  $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: "#container", scroll: false });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(e, u) {
      items.push(u.draggable.data('item'));
      calcPrice('add');
    },
    out: function(e, u) {
      calcPrice('remove');
      items.splice($.inArray(u.draggable.data('item', items),1));
    }
  });
});
```

```
  <div id="container">
    <div id="droppable"></div>
    <div class="draggable" data-item="1" data-price="541">541</div>
    <div class="draggable" data-item="2" data-price="542">542</div>
  </div>
```

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/exilos/1/edit

Comment: @estrar..i think the problem is with circular reference..did u check ur console log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problematic line in ur code is
 `items.splice($.inArray(u.draggable.data('item', items),1));`
I have changed that to 
`items.splice($.inArray(u.draggable.data('item'), items));`
NaN problem is not there anymore ..u have to check the calculation of price .. 
 [see this link](http://jsbin.com/exilos/4/edit)

Comment: Ahh great. Thank you! Yeah, I see the problem with the calculation, if the item is dropped repeatedly within the red container it will add up every time. You got your upvote now too ;)